# Calculate from 2 textboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create 2 text boxes, when I type in the first one the sum gets added and  viewed at the second text box, but when I give the code it doesn't run correctly.

```
<script>
function addNumbs() {
var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
var sum = n1 +n2;
document.getElementById("num2").value =sum
if (sum >1000)
    window.alert("Over the limit babe!!")
}
</script>

<body>
<input type="text" value=0 id= num1>
<input type="text" value=0 id= num2>
<button onclick("addNumbs()")>Add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you choose to try and replace one of the values with the sum? Why not add it as innerText of an empty `<span>` (for usability's sake)?

Comment: @Nosnetrom this isn't relevant for question.

Comment: You can make it work, just change example like this. <button onclick="addNumbs()">Add</button>

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo: It's not `onclick("addNumbs()")`, it's `onclick="addNumbs()"`

Comment: That's not a typo, it's a misunderstanding of the html syntax for event attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the syntax for the onclick attribute of your button. Try this:

```js
function addNumbs() {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  console.log(n1, n2);
  var sum = n1 + n2;
  document.getElementById("num2").value = sum;
  if (sum >1000){
    window.alert("Over the limit babe!!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value=0 id= num1>
<input type="text" value=0 id= num2>
<button onclick="addNumbs()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is the correct implementation:

```js
function addNumbs() {
document.getElementById("number2").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value) + parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
if (parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value) > 1000)
    window.alert("Over the limit babe!!")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="number1">
<input type="text" value="0" id="number2">
<button onclick = "addNumbs();">Add</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You syntax of setting onclick event in html is wrong it should be 
And use `+` to convert strings to `Number` instead of using `parseInt`

```
<button onclick = "addNumbs()">Add</button>
```

However I would suggest you to use modern way to set events using `addEventListener`.

```js
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click',addNumbs)

function addNumbs() {
    var n1 = +document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var n2 = +document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var sum = n1 +n2;
    document.getElementById("num2").value =sum
    if (sum >1000)
        alert("Over the limit babe!!")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value=0 id= num1>
<input type="text" value=0 id= num2>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: You've added an incorrect `+`. It should be `sum = n1 + n2`, not `sum +=`

Comment: The scope of sum doesn't actually matter in this case.

Comment: @Cat I thought it was a mistype I updated my answer